# Excel VLOOKUP/ IF/MATCH help needed

Tags: excel, if-statement, match, vlookup

Hoping someone can help me with an excel formula. I have two tabs (first tab would pull from second, second tab would be a report that gets copy pasted that sometimes has certain categories and sometimes it doesn't). What formula can i use to match a cell (line/column) if the column sometimes exists and sometimes it doesn't?). Would this be a match/if? I need the exact formula as I have tried many combos and it's just not working.

More concrete, daily sales on the first tab. The report that gets copy pasted in the second tab would have has sales categories (sometimes one of the categories gets pulled does not exist and gets replaced by another category) depending on what sales happen that day. The categories in columns would be "main dining", "library", "bar" and the sales categories by lines for each of these would be "Food", "Liquor", "beer".

I can provide additional information if needed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could use a index/match formula with and iferror statement around it look for the alternative category if the value is not there.

Comment: What about `IfError()`?  It works like `=IfError(Vlookup(...),"Not Found/Error")`.  But, personally, I like `Index/Match`, so I'd follow what @VBAPete suggests.

Comment: just use T function

Comment: How can i use the T function if I'm looking for a value in a cell that might be category x or category y depending on the day?

Comment: @VBAPete what would be the exact formula? I'm not familiar with index

Comment: It would look something like `=IfError(index(...,match(...,...,0)),"Not Found/Error")`. Do you have an example of your data set and I can write you the formula.

Comment: @VBAPete I wish I could email you the sheet i am working on. Any way to do that? Otherwise i'll try to explain

Comment: Most people add a screenshot of data their issue, so that it can also help other users with similar issues.

Comment: @VBAPete I can't seem to add a screen shot so i'll try to explain it

Comment: You can add the screenshot to your original post. Just select edit and then click on the image button.

Comment: @VBAPete unfortunately i cannot add images as I do not have any points. ..

Comment: If you can not add images, then I suggest hosting the images externally, and providing a link to those images in your question.  It's really difficult for any of us to help you without being able to see the structure of the data or how it's organized.  It doesn't have to be real data, just dummy/example data, but something that shows us what you're working with.

Comment: https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/43c5e793-69ee-47fc-96ea-ee5f6c29d2de

Comment: You guys are awesome! Thank you for your patience and help!

Comment: @VBAPete  can you please look at the link i posted and let me know what you think. It's probably an easy fix- I'm just not that good at this.

Comment: Can't open link. I will try it later on a different computer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your sheets are called, so I left as sheet1 and sheet2, but the formula below should do what you are after. Please note that the categories need to be exactly the same, so you can't have "MDR" in one sheet and "Main Dinning" in the other.

```
=IfError(SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$8=Sheet2!$A2)*(Sheet1!$B1:$F1=Sheet2!$B1),Sheet1!$B$2:$F$8),"0")
```

You should be able to paste this formula into cell B2 and then pull it down and right to populate the entire data sheet. For your info, `Sheet1!$A$2:$A$8`captures the row criteria range and `Sheet1!$B1:$F1` the column criteria, while `Sheet2!$A2` and `Sheet2!$B1` are picking the criteria to look for. If the value cannot be found, the formula returns a 0.